# JBoss 7(EAP 6) MDB integration with Websphere MQ using JNDI on LDAP

Tags: jboss, ldap, jndi, ibm-mq

I want to write a application using MDB(message driven bean) and deploy to jboss eap 6.1 server.

My MQ is IBM Websphere MQ, and I have a LDAP server to locate the MQ JNDI namespace, and I know how to get/put message using JNDI and JMS.

But when coming to JBoss, I don't know how to configure MDB to listen to the MQ. I want to use the JNDI on LDAP, and write a message consumer on the JBoss server. And I don't want to hard code configuration in the annotation.

I did a lot of searching, but no any solutions. Can anybody show me the detailed process?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I'm looking at the same situation (specically *not* using annotations as I don't want to touch the existing MDBs)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible due to the limitations in the IBM JCA.  The IBM JCA builds a managed connection factory for each MDB deployment based on the MDBs activation specification.  This will typically have your MQ host, port, channel, etc. specified.

You can not specify a the JNDI name of a connection factory to use.  This is a bit odd as you can specify the JNDI name of your destination.

Functionality similar to the LDAP external context can be achieved using the IBM Client Channel Definition Table (CCDT).